# Writer Monad Nested Twice

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, writer-monad

I am trying to nest writer monad twice using Monad Transformers. Here is a sketch:

```
import Control.Monad.Identity
import Control.Monad.Writer

data Struct = S Bool

instance Monoid Struct where
    mempty =  S True
    mappend (S a) (S b) = S (a && b)

data Collision = C Bool

instance Monoid Collision where
    mempty =  C False
    mappend (C a) (C b) = C (a || b)

type CSInt = WriterT Collision (WriterT Struct Identity) Int

foo :: Int -> CSInt
foo x = do (tell (S False)) ; return x
```

The `foo` function does not compile, as I need to use `tell` on `Struct` monad, not `Collision`. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having multiple similar layers is in fact one case where the `mtl` approach, which is meant to make `lift` implicit, has trouble as you mentionned. So you can use `lift` explicitly.

```
lift :: Writer Struct Bool -> WriterT Collision (Writer Struct) Bool
```

Thus

```
foo x = do lift (tell (S False)) ; return x
```

Comment: Thanks. If I may ask a follow-up question. How can I define function unwrapping all this, similar to `runWriter`.  Signature:  `runW :: CSInt -> (Int, Bool, Bool)`

Comment: You can use `runWriter`/`runWriterT`, or just pattern match on the `CSInt` (see the definition of `WriterT`).